# Is it possible to run tests under testtools framework within Python script just like unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have been using Python's unittest framework all the while, but then decided to switch to testtools. In unittest, you can invoke test from within the script, but testtools does not seem to offer the same capability. Its documentation only shows how to invoke from command-line-interface (CLI). Is it possible to run tests from within Python script under testtools framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`testtools` is a set of extensions to `unittest`, not a wholesale replacement.

you can still use `unittest` loaders/runners, or any other compatible runner (like [`nose`](https://nose.readthedocs.org)).

for example, here is a `testtools.TestCase` derived class run with `unittest.main()`:

```
import testtools
import unittest

class SampleTestCase(testtools.TestCase):
    def test_it(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```